# Does CorelDraw have a native read resolution for reading SVG's?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, resolution, corel-draw

Does **CorelDraw** has a default read resolution for `SVG`'s? The only DPI settings that will show me the number of pixels exactly as they were created is 96. Is that Corel's native DPI resolution for reading `svg` files or am I missing something?

If I ramp up the resolution to 300 DPI I get wrong numbers, however 96 seems ok.

Comment: can you tell us what equipment you are using for these stickers? I am still struggling to understand why you need to convert the svg to anything pixel-based in the first place.

Comment: I don't know the answer but it sounds arbitrary. CorelDraw is vector based, as is SVG. Once imported, you should be able to resize it as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple resources I found that seem similar to your issue.

[CorelDRAW doesn't correctly import svg files](https://coreldraw.com/forums/t/37422.aspx)

Here's the short of a [long winded answer](http://forum.make-the-cut.com/discussion/1424/dpi-question):

> What it comes down to is that SVG files describe paths in some sort of
>   units, and MTC needs to know how many units in the SVG file equal 1
>   inch in MTC. If you do not check the `Use Actual:` check box in MTC,
>   then it uses the caret size to determine the overall height of the
>   imported SVG file. If you do check the `Use Actual:` check box in MTC,
>   it will use the value in the DPI box to convert from the units used in
>   the SVG file to inches that are used in MTC. For designs created in
>   Inkscape, using 90 in the DPI box will import the SVG at the
>   "designed" size (for the reason I described above).